# Free font similar to Engraver MT?

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm looking for a free font similar to Engraver MT. Any suggestions?

[image: image of Engraver MT]

Answer (score 2):

Try plugging your image into [whatfontis.com](http://www.whatfontis.com/). If you check the "Free Alternatives" box after identifying your characters, it'll give you lots of results that are close but not exact.

[OPTICrawModern](http://www.ffonts.net/OPTICrawModern.font) looks pretty similar, but there are lots to choose from.

[image]